# Auto adjust element height depending on another element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Suppose there are two  elements vertically placed together, like the following image:

[Image of two divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfILe.png)

The condition is `div1`'s height is auto/dynamic, since it depends on its content. 
The question is how to set css style of `div2` to make sure the sum of heights of `div1` and `div2` is fixed, for example:

`<div1>` and `<div2>` has total height of `1000px`, while `div1`'s height is auto, when `div1` has height of `200px`, the height of `div2` will auto adjust to `1000-200=800px`; when `div1` has height of `400px`, the height of `div2` will auto adjust to `1000-400=600px`;

Is there any solution about this? I tried to use flex, but cannot figure out how.

Comment: I already used flex-grow: 1 to solved it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex: 1` on `.div2`. This is same as setting `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` to 1 and `flex-basis` to auto. Now, the height of `.div1` can be anything and `.div2` will grow or shrink to fill in the remaining height.

```css
.parent-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px;
  background: black;
}

.div1 {
  height: 200px;
  background: pink;
}

.div2 {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I did find out this solution, but it has a bug if you found out before, when set the div2 to flex-grow: 1 (it indeed will shrink and fill the remain space), then any sub-element inside div2 using height: 100% cannot inherit the height, I tried many times, still cannot inherit, do you know why??? thanks

Comment: The child element will occupy the full height of `.div2` if you have set the `height:100%`. Works as expected.

Comment: @YuiMoe Using `height: 100%` on a flex child sub-element is the wrong way. It is not a bug, the sub-element can't simply pick up the height as it is not actually set, as its `height` has the default `auto`, which `flex` won't change. When one need the sub-element to take _full height of its parent_, one need to use nested flex containers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to jquery, it is simple,

```js
var totalHeight = 500;
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.two').height(totalHeight-$('.one').height());
});

//only if you want to update the content after page load.
$(document).bind('DOMSubtreeModified',function (){
    $('.two').height(totalHeight-$('.one').height());
})
```

```css
div{
    width: 300px;
    background: red;
}
.two{
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">one</div>
<div class="two">two</div>
```

I have set total height 500px here.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.two').height(totalHeight-$('.one').height());
});
```

This will set the height of second div on page load. and

```
$(document).bind('DOMSubtreeModified',function (){
    $('.two').height(totalHeight-$('.one').height());
})
```

This is required only if you want to change the content later after page load. Other wise you can ignore this.